# How to programmatically set the SSL context of a Axis client?

Tags: java, ssl, soap, axis

In a very old project we are using a client developed with Axis 1.4 to call a SOAP web service. This web service use mutual authentication mechanism, so we have a private certificate installed inside a keystore and a public key installed inside a truststore.

The SOAP client is used inside a task of a BPM process. We can't and we don't want to use JVM global truststore and keystore. Then we can't configure programmatically JVM global trustore and keystore:

```
// Keystore
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", fileKeystore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", pwdKeystore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");
// Truststore
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", fileTruststore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", pwdTruststore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
```

An approach like that will force us to synchronize the process on the JVM properties and we don't want to do that. Moreover, there are other java processes running on the machine.

My question is: Does Axis 1.4 offer some API to specify which keystore and truststore to use for a specific web service call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, googling a little I've found the answer to my question. The answer is that using solely Axis 1.4 it is not possible to specify a different keystore/truststore for each service invocation. We need an external library, called [axistools](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/axistools-maven-plugin/1.4).

The library implements a particular kind of `EngineConfiguration` that allows you to specify for each service call a keystore and/or a truststore.

The following example will be explicative:

```
// Setting up the configuration
SSLClientAxisEngineConfig config = new SSLClientAxisEngineConfig();
config.setKeystore("path/to/your/keystore");
config.setKeystoreType("JKS");
config.setKeystorePassword("password");
config.setTruststore("path/to/your/truststore");
config.setTruststoreType("JKS");
config.setTruststorePassword("password");
// Very important: without this method invocation 
// the client won't work at all
config.initialize();

// Calling the web service
URL url = new URL("https://localhost:8443/someService");
WebServiceLocator locator = new WebServiceLocator (config);
WebServiceSoap port = locator.getWebServiceSoap(url);
WebServiceSoapStub stub = (WebServiceSoapStub) port;
stub.serviceMethod();
```

And that's all, folks!!!

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/axistools-maven-plugin/1.4 jar doesn't has the mentioned SSLClientAxisEngineConfig  class.Can you please give correct maven dependency

Comment: Oh gosh, you're right! Try to retrieve the library from [here](https://github.com/linhkuivanen/axistools) or from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadaxisssl14jar.htm). Let me know.

Comment: The class SSLClientAxisEngineConfig  is different in the jars mentioned.config.initialize(); doesn't exists in latter. I tried the latter still I get "unable to get valid certification path"

Comment: I bet what you are searching for is [this](http://wiki.apache.org/ws/FrontPage/Axis/DynamicSSLConfig) link. In the end of the page you find the `axistools.jar`.

Comment: Yes thats what I was looking for.. Thanks .Used it but getting untrusted certificate chain error.

Comment: Only one question: if you add the certificate to the global trustore, do you experience the same problem? If so, it is a problem of the certificare chain, I guess.

Comment: Yeah got that chain issue resolved, now I am getting Axis 405 method not allowed, trying to fix it.